# Error with Geocoding - Error 1 and Error 8

Tags: swift, swiftui, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am pulling all of the users locations inside of Firebase storage, and when I try to geocode them into lat and long coordinates, I am getting the error `2022-07-26 15:40:39.676845-0400 Polygon[96779:3864577] [MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x6000004c2c90>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x6000034f0870> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)` and `Error Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"`

My code seems to be working fine, and when I take one of the addresses and geocode them in a different project, they work well. Please take a look at the code below and tell me of any errors or if I missed something?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocationUI
import Firebase

struct Place: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct MapView: View {
    
    var empireStateBuilding =
    Place(name: "Empire State Building", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.748433, longitude: -73.985656))
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    @State var address = ""
    @State var addresses:[String] = []
    
    
    
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    @State private var result = "result of lat & long"
    @State private var lat = 0.0
    @State private var long = 0.0
    @State private var country = "country name"
    @State private var state = "state name"
    @State private var zip = "zip code"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tint(.pink)
                
                LocationButton(.currentLocation) {
                    viewModel.requestAllowOnceLocationPermission()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .symbolVariant(.fill)
                .tint(.pink)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.trailing, 300)
                
                Button  {
                    
                    print(address)
                    
                    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                        if((error) != nil){
                            print("Error", error ?? "")
                        }
                        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                            if let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location.coordinate {
                                print("Lat: \(coordinates.latitude) -- Long: \(coordinates.longitude)")
                                //added code
                                result = "Lat: \(coordinates.latitude) -- Long: \(coordinates.longitude)"
                                lat = coordinates.latitude
                                long = coordinates.longitude
                            }
                            
                        }
                    })
                    
                    
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                }
                .padding(.leading, 300)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                
                Text("\(result)")
            }
            
            List(0..<addresses.count, id: \.self) {i in Text(addresses[i]) }
            
            
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            downloadServerData()
        })
    }
    
    func downloadServerData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("UserInfo").addSnapshotListener {(snap, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("There is an error")
                return
            }
            for i in snap.documentChanges {
                let documentId = i.document.documentID
                if let address = i.document.get("address") as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        addresses.append("\(address)")
                        print(address)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct AnnotatedItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}

//LocationButton
final class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40, longitude: 120), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 100, longitudeDelta: 100))
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func requestAllowOnceLocationPermission() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager( _ _manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else {
            // show an error
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: latestLocation.coordinate,
                span:MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:0.05, longitudeDelta:0.05))
        }
    }
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


struct MapView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using forced unwrapping in a various places, it will make your app **crash** when there is a nil.
This is what `!` is supposed to do. It is a bad idea to use `!`, use `if let ...` instead, 
like I showed you in your previous question.

Comment: at what point is the error being generated?  Is it from`didFailWithError`?  Have you stepped through the code to understand at what point the location data becomes invalid?

Comment: I fixed the first comment, using the if let approach. For the second comment it is from `didFailWithError` i have updated the code snippet above for the if let approach if it helps. Here is the error for the didFailWithError: `2022-07-27 15:23:20.665146-0400 Polygon[10026:4359584] [MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600002f08340>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x600001f699e0> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"` and `Error Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"`

Comment: you still have forced unwrapping at: `let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate`. Also look at my answer to your first question at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114607/app-returning-type-optional-needs-to-return-type-string
 for how to do `if let address = i.document.get("address") as? String {...}`.

Comment: I fixed it by using the `as? String {...}`, but the app still isn't geocoding—the same error. Updated the code again

Comment: Do not use forced unwrapping, that is **do not use `!`**, 
you still have them at: `let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate.` and  
`for i in snap!.documentChanges {...}`.

Comment: I fixed the other parts on force unwrapping, but I was not able to run the app if I remove the `!= nil`. I am still getting an error even now after I've done all of this. Is is a problem with the geocoder?

Comment: can you show us what error you get when you use  `print("\(err)")` instead of `print("There is an error")` in `downloadServerData()`.

Comment: There is no error there, but when I run my app, I am getting the error of `2022-07-30 22:51:55.038690-0400 Polygon[24749:351754] [MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600002720cf0>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x600001716880> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"`. Doing some googling I could see that Code=1 means that Apple's Geocoder couldn't figure out what the string being passed meant. Is there any way that I could feed the multiple addresses from the database into a function for the geocoding?